# Can I perform a mixed effects Cox model on population of different size?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, survival, sample-size, proportional-hazards

I want to test the survival of multiple populations with 2 different treatments and include 2 random effects as well. Hence, I want to perform a mixed effects Cox model.

I count how many ants died within a colony once a week for a period of 5 weeks. During my last mortality count, I also count the number of remaining living ants.

I am using ant colonies where some individual are randomly escaping from their boxes. Hence, the population size is going to be different at the end of the experiment. Moreover, I would like to collect samples (aka individual ants) from some colonies (and not others) at different time points (week 1, 3 and 5), modifying again the population size.

Therefore, I am doubting whether the mixed effects Cox model is the right way to analyze my data, and that maybe I should look at mortality within each population and then compare them with a glmm.

I hope this was clear, it is my first time asking a question!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit your question to provide more information about how you measure the ant numbers and the mortality. A Cox model analyzes only the individuals at risk at each time so that might be OK, depending on the experimental design. Much has to do with how often you measure mortality: if it's more or less continuous in time then a Cox model is often a good choice, if it's just a few measurement times then a binomial generalized linear model can be better.

Comment: I edited my question. I believe the Cox model  might be a better fit then.
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A death rate is the number of deaths per number of individuals at risk. If you know how many were removed from the survival study, for example how many you took to sample and if you have video records of all those escaping, then you know how many were at risk during any time period. Then you can make a reasonable estimate of the survival fraction over time.

If you don't know exactly how many ants escaped between observation times, however, things get more complicated. Presumably you can get the overall number of escapees by taking the difference between the number at the start and the number accounted for by deaths, removal by sampling, and the number left at the end. You will, however, have to make some estimate of how those escapes changed over time in order to estimate the number of ants at risk of death during each time interval.

With only 5 time points, I think that a binomial (mixed) model makes more sense than a Cox model. It will also more easily accommodate your estimate, based on the escape rate, of the numbers at risk during each time interval. A simple way to set up the data is to have a single data row for each box for each week, with an indicator for the week as one of the predictors and with the outcome being a two-column matrix of `(number dead, number alive)` for that week, where `number alive` is the difference between your estimate of the total number during the week minus the number that died. See the R help page for `family` for that way to represent data for a binomial regression. If you treat `week` as an unordered categorical variable rather than numeric, that comes closest to a Cox model in that it makes no assumptions about the baseline survival function.